# How to use a method in a common component such that it is used by one component that needs it and other component that doesn't need it?

Tags: reactjs

i have a common component named "Common" that gets image from a url. Before it fetches the image i want to set the state of a variable to true and once fetching done set the state to false. And i need to use the state in parent component say "ParentComponent" to add a spinner. I achieve this by defining a method set_loading in parent component as below

```
set_loading = () => this.setState({loading:!this.state.loading});
```

and i pass this method to child component like below,

```
return ( 
    <ChildComponent 
        on_set_loading = {this.set_loading}
```

Below is the child component

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    load_image = () => {
    this.props.on_set_loading();
    client.get(this.props.get_url, this.unmount)
        .finally(() => this.props.on_set_loading())
        .then(({response}) => {
            //do something
        })
        .catch(() => {})
    };

}
```

However there is also another component that uses this child component like below,

```
export default class AnotherComponentSharingChild extends React.component {
    return (
         <ChildComponent />
    )
}
```

Here we see that anothercomponentsharingchild component doesnt send set_loading method to the child component. So this throws an error set_loading is not a function.

How can i solve this. I want this loading state for the parent component to add a spinner based on the loading state. But doesnt want that loading state status to anothercomponentsharingchild component.

Could someone help me solving this. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just check for the prop: if (this.props.on_set_loading) { }

Comment: when your method **load_image**  runs? is that for any Component sharing the child?

Comment: @Hsaidooo: Yes load_image is for any component that shares the child it is mandatory to be run

Comment: So why you need the loading just for the first Parent?

Comment: yes only for parent

Comment: You can check if it exists like @rrd mentioned, or set a default prop of an empty function for it

Comment: @tomericco: is it possible to check for its existence in finally statement? if so how could i do it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use default props in this case:

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    static get defaultProps() {
        return {
            on_set_loading: () => {}
        };
    }    

    load_image = () => {
    this.props.on_set_loading();
    client.get(this.props.get_url, this.unmount)
        .finally(() => this.props.on_set_loading())
        .then(({response}) => {
            //do something
        })
        .catch(() => {})
    };

}
```